# Ansible: installing roles in requirements file upon playbook execution

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy

`Vagrant` has a very nice feature called [`galaxy_role_file`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_common.html#galaxy_role_file) that allows one to point to a `requirements.yml` file and to install the roles listed there upon `vagrant up` (provided that the vm is configured to use `ansible` provisioner).

My question is whether there is such an option in `ansible` itself, given that I was unable to find it available [configurations](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-configuration-settings).

or do we always have to explicitly type `ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml` before each first playbook execution?